# Why do we use Context Compat and Activity Compat?

Tags: android

I was writing a code which asks user the permission to use location:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
```

Why do we use them and why cant we just write `checkSelfPermission`?

Comment: Obviously because on older API those methods do not extist

Comment: Ok, but why do we use both `ContextCompat` and `ActivityCompat`? Can I write `ContextCompat.requestPermissions.`?

Comment: If you find such method in Context class

Comment: Because you can check permissions from any context (activity, service, broadcast receiver etc), however permission requests are only allowed from within activities.